# Need advice to integrate videochat function to my Blazor App

Tags: blazor

I need some advice. Is there any simple solution to integrate Videochat modul to my Blazor webapp?
I googled for it a lot but still nothing. I hope somebody could help me :)

Comment: I guess not, there isn't. May be you can use the js videochat modul of your choice and try to integrate it with JsInterop

Comment: Thank you! i will looking forward to it

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

https://jitsi.org/api/

https://jitsi.github.io/handbook/docs/dev-guide/dev-guide-iframe

embed this to your blazor page. customize it as you wish

Comment: The question was *how* to integrate, not which library to use